# The faucet is leaking. How do I remove the faucet handle pieces?

Tags: faucet, removal

I can remove the hot and cold handle pieces, but the rest of the handle is not coming off to get to the screw below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same cheap Glacier Bay faucet in one of my bathrooms. There is a screw in the top of the part of the hot & cold that actually rotates. Very similar (not sure if it is identical, but should be close enough) item at [Glacier Bay Teapot 4 in.](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Glacier-Bay-Teapot-4-in-Centerset-2-Handle-Low-Arc-Bathroom-Faucet-in-Chrome-67092W-6A01/300687487). Download the [Replacement Parts List](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/2c/2cc444e4-8ebd-4377-ad9d-ed7491077256.pdf) and what I am talking about is screw # 2 underneath # 1 and # 14 in the diagram.